# create a git branch with the current system date

Tags: bash, git, shell, git-branch

i will be running a automated deployment on every day.

so i need to create a child branch from develop, is there any way to create a branch from develop with the current system time. just like below

> git checkout -b 'date +"%d-%m-%y"-dev-release-"%I"'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
git checkout -b `date +"%d-%m-%y"-dev-release-"%I"`
```

or

```
git checkout -b $(date +"%d-%m-%y"-dev-release-"%I")
```

Bacticks and `$()` means: execute the command and replace the command with its output.

See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/CommandSubstitution